# Windows 10: Move 2nd monitor windows on disconnect to 2nd virtual desktop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, virtual-desktop

At work my laptop is connected to an external monitor which I use as secondary monitor (i.e. extended desktop).

When attending meetings in other rooms with my laptop and I have to disconnect the external monitor. I would like to have the open windows of the external monitor automatically being moved to a separate virtual desktop instead back to the primary monitor. When I reconnect the external monitor the windows of the 2nd virtual desktop should be moved back to the external monitor again.

Is that somehow possible?

So what I basically want is that a second virtual desktop actually acts as a "virtual" extended monitor as long as the physical external monitor is not connected.

Any ideas are appreciated.